# trying to include a php script in an html page

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to integrate the following script in my html page, but so far I am not very successful. Is there any cleaner way to achieve this ?

```
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
                //$('#console-event').html('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'))
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("Change event: " + this.id + "..." + this.checked);                         
                doSomething(this.id);
                <?php require('common.php');
                $result = $db->add_news('titles');
                }?>                                     })
                }
            )
        </script>
```

Comment: use ajax ...... js is client side

Comment: what has this got to do with PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: You can't integrate `PHP` codes in an `HTML` page. You have to save your page as `.php` first before any php code within the script is been executed

Comment: Thank you. Does that means that if my page would be saved as php (with the structure of an html page), it would work?

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE - actually, no - that's not true. It merely has to be a page that the server knows to process as PHP.